Asymptotic distribution of Pearson Chi Squared Statistic
I am currently studying Generalized Linear Models, and I quite confused by the following statement.

For context, the F statistic is used to test whether model B (Model A is nested within model B), contains significant information, and is able to explain more of the variance, not simply to the increase in model complexity. $D^A$ and $D^B$ are the deviances of the models A and B respectively, $s$ is the increase in the number of parameters from model A to B and $X^2$ is the Pearson chi-squared statistic which is defined below

Here, $Y_i$ is the response variable, $\hat{\mu_i}$ is the fitted mean for the GLM, $v(\hat{\mu_i})$ is the variance function for the underlying distribution.
My question is why does the $X^2$ statistic follow approximately chi squared distribution regardless of the GLM distribution? I have studied linear models and understand how we get this result if the underlying distribution is normal, but I can't seem to figure out how this extends to other distributions, even if approximate.
